# Normalizing json using pandas with inconsistent nested lists/dictionaries

Tags: python, json, pandas, typeerror, json-normalize

I've been using pandas' json_normalize for a bit but ran into a problem with specific json file, similar to the one seen here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/37783#issuecomment-1148052109

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve the data within the Ats -> Ats dict and return any null values (like the one seen in the ID:101 entry) as NaN values in the dataframe. Ignoring errors within the json_normalize call doesn't prevent the TypeError that stems from trying to iterate through a null value.

Any advice or methods to receive a valid dataframe out of data with this structure is greatly appreciated!

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = """[
    {
        "ID": "100",
        "Ats": {
            "Ats": [
                {
                    "Name": "At1",
                    "Desc": "Lazy At"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "ID": "101",
        "Ats": null
    }
]"""
data = json.loads(data)
df = pd.json_normalize(data, ["Ats", "Ats"], "ID", errors='ignore')
df.head()
```

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I tried to iterate through the Ats dictionary, which would work normally for the data with ID 100 but not with ID 101. I expected ignoring errors within the function to return a NaN value in a dataframe but instead received a TypeError for trying to iterate through a null value.

The desired output would look like this: [Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxIh0.png)

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Question has been edited, I hope that format works

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a DataFrame from the `data` normally (without `pd.json_normalize`) and then transform it to requested form afterwards:

```py
import json

import pandas as pd

data = """\
[
    {
        "ID": "100",
        "Ats": {
            "Ats": [
                {
                    "Name": "At1",
                    "Desc": "Lazy At"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "ID": "101",
        "Ats": null
    }
]"""

data = json.loads(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["Ats"] = df["Ats"].str["Ats"]
df = df.explode("Ats")

df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("Ats").apply(pd.Series, dtype=object)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    ID Name     Desc
0  100  At1  Lazy At
1  101  NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach can be more efficient when it comes to dealing with large datasets.

```py
data = json.loads(data)
desired_data = list(
    map(lambda x: pd.json_normalize(x, ["Ats", "Ats"], "ID").to_dict(orient="records")[0]
    if x["Ats"] is not None
    else {"ID": x["ID"], "Name": np.nan, "Desc": np.nan}, data))
    
df = pd.DataFrame(desired_data)
```

Output:

```
  Name     Desc   ID
0  At1  Lazy At  100
1  NaN      NaN  101
```

You might want to consider using this simple `try` and `except` approach when working with small datasets. In this case, whenever an error is found it should append new row to DataFrame with `NAN`.

Example:

```py
data = json.loads(data)
df = pd.DataFrame()
for item in data:
    try:
        df = df.append(pd.json_normalize(item, ["Ats", "Ats"], "ID")) 
    except TypeError:
        df = df.append({"ID" : item["ID"], "Name": np.nan, "Desc": np.nan}, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Name     Desc   ID
0  At1  Lazy At  100
1  NaN      NaN  101
```

Comment: This might be fine for small datasets, but:
a) df.append is deprecated
b) because df.append creates a new dataframe for each call, looping it over many records has negative implications for time complexity

Comment: You are absolutely right @Payback. I provided that answer abase in the dataset in the question. But I will add a more concise and efficient approach when dealing with large dataset and I hope that helps.

Comment: I added another approach to the answer @Payback. You can give it a try to see if that solves the efficiency issues.